# escaping characters in as3 as javascript does

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, utf-8

I am having trouble escaping special characters in as3.

```
trace( escape("who are ü?") );
```

returns who%20are%20%uFFFD%3F

or

```
trace( encodeURIComponent("who are ü?") );
```

returns who%20are%20%EF%BF%BD%3F

while in javascript this

```
alert( encodeURIComponent("who are ü?") );
```

returns who%20are%20%C3%BC%3F

and

```
alert( escape("who are ü?") );
```

returns who%20are%20%FC%3F

Any suggestions how to get as3 to return escaped special characters as javascript is?  Why is as3 apparently choking?

(here is a good reference: http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/actionscript/as3-escape-vs-as2-escape-122046.html )

Comment: What I get with flex 3.0 is this: who%20are%20%FC%3F Isn't this what you want? Can you recheck? This is with a demo AIR app (and I am running Flex 3.0)!

Comment: Unfortunately, my trace statements are "who%20are%20%uFFFD%3F" (using flex3).

Comment: The code point %uFFFD flag tells you 'ü' did not get saved correctly. Did you make any changes to the locale? I believe that you are looking at console output.

Comment: I didn't change the locale... however, it looks like what i am looking for is utf-8 compliant encodeURIComponent for browser compatibility (which as3 isn't giving me either.  i get "who%20are%20%EF%BF%BD%3F")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like AS is escaping the string as UTF-16, while the Javascript example is escaping as UTF-8. [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions%28Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5%29) doesn't define how to deal with non-ascii characters, and so it's been deprecated as of JavaScript 1.5. You should use the function [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead, which is defined as escaping as UTF-8 - This should be consistent across different implementations. If you require the AS behaviour, I don't think there is a native function in Javascript, but you can use the functions provided [here](http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/conversion.php).

Answer (score 1):

Although my IDE (intellij) was displaying, saving, and loading special characters, they were being saved in 1252.  Switching to UTF-8 has fixed this.